# Bind Stimulsoft report to a table from MSSQL

Tags: javascript, stimulsoft

I have spent many days trying everything I have found on the forum/samples/github, What I want to do :
- I have a table in Sql Server
- I have a report designer in my single page application ( Stimulsoft reports.js)
- I need to fill the report with the table's rows ( so that the user can preview the report ).

Currently, the report template is created server-side ( asp.net core ), using this code :

```
[HttpPost]
public override async Task Post([FromBody] Report[] elements)
{
var report = new StiReport();

var ds = GetDocumentDataSet();
report.RegData(AppName, ds);
report.Dictionary.Synchronize();
foreach (var element in elements)
element.Layout = report.SaveToJsonString();
return await base.Post(elements);
}
private DataSet GetDocumentDataSet()
{
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (var connection = Use().GetConnection())
{
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
var table = new DataTable($"{nameof(Document)}");
command.CommandText = $"select top 1 * from {nameof(Document)}";

connection.Open();
table.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
ds.Tables.Add(table);
}
}
return ds;
}
```

This code puts the table, the columns with their types in the dictionnary, it works. Client side, when I load the report using this code :

```
report.load(dataReport.Layout);
```

I can see this in the dictionnary : https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzMLL.jpg

That's cool, I have just to provide the data now, server side I get the data this way :

```
public async Task ReportSearch()
{
var rows = new List();
var columns = new List();
var types = new List();
using (var connection = Use().GetConnection())
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
command.CommandText = $"select * from {nameof(Document)}";
connection.Open();
var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
while (await reader.ReadAsync())
{
var values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
reader.GetValues(values);
rows.Add(values);
}
foreach (DataRow c in reader.GetSchemaTable().Rows)
{
columns.Add((string)c["ColumnName"]);
types.Add(((Type)c["DataType"]).FullName);
}
}

return new // As seen in your github sample
{
columns = columns,
notice = "",
types = types,
rows = rows,
success = true
};
}
```

And client-side, I try to fill-in this way :

```
const report = new Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport();
if (dataReport.Layout != null && dataReport.Layout != "") {
report.load(dataReport.Layout);
}
$.ajax({
type: "Post",
url: "api/Search/ReportSearch",
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json",
success: (data) => {

var dataSet = new Stimulsoft.System.Data.DataSet(appName);
dataSet.readJson(JSON.stringify(data));

report.regData(dataSet.dataSetName, dataSet.dataSetName, dataSet);
report.dictionary.synchronize();
designer.report = report;
}
});
```

But I get this :( : https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXKZu.jpg

Trust me, I have tried everything I have found. I would prefer to send the data as a table ( array of array of objects ) rather than an array of json objects because each object has the same properties, so the first method is ligher than the second one and it would be faster to transfer/parse.

Could someone help please ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a sample from [GitHub](https://github.com/stimulsoft/Samples-NET.Core-CSharp/blob/master/Managing-Data-in-Reports/Controllers/HomeController.cs) lines(74-86):

```
        if (requestParams.Connection.Type == StiConnectionType.MSSQL)
        {
            string connectionString = requestParams.Connection.ConnectionString;
            string queryString = requestParams.Connection.QueryString;

            StiDataResult result = new StiDataResult()
            {
                Columns = new string[2] { "Column1", "Column2" },
                Types = new string[2] { "number", "string" },
                Rows = new string[3][] { new string[2] { "1", "Row1" }, new string[2] { "2", "Row2" }, new string[2] { "3", "Row3" } }
            };
            return StiNetCoreViewer.GetReportDataResult(this, result);
        }
```